# Netbeans PHP - how to run all the files in a directory

Tags: php, file, netbeans

I am running PHP files in my NetBeans with a shell script command. So far so good. I can run individual files without any problem. Sometimes, however, I would like to run all the files in a directory (and it's subdirectories). I tried selecting the directory and hitting the shortcut for "Run" but nothing happens. If I select multiple files and hit "Run" only the last one selected will be run.

I am using the latest NetBeans 7.0.1 on MacOS 10.6. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of such a feature. What I'd do with NetBeans is create a php application and in the main file write some code calling each php file... it will look ugly but I think it's the only way

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, too, but I would prefer to avoid this solution/workaround. Just as a comparison in Ecplipse you can hit "run" on a directory, and all the files in it and it's subdirectories will be run. Also, your solution is not really applicable for my request because I would have to write such a file in each folder I am ever wanting to run independently and there may be hundreds of such directories. Obviously this is unacceptable in a corporate environment.